# Road Graph Plugin in QGIS 3.2.2

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

Where can the Road Graph plugin be found in QGIS 3.2.2?

It is not among the Plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that core plugin has been removed and instead its [main functions have been added](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html?highlight=shortest#network-analysis-library) to the *Processing Toolbox*:

[image: Shortest path]

Comment: @MK - Most welcome, hope it helped :)

Comment: Shortest path tool looks very different in QGIS 3.2.2 than 2.8. Any suggestions how to set time and distance parameters? The tutorial on the link below is applicable only for QGIS 2.8. https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/network_analysis.html

Comment: @MK - Sorry, haven't used the tool in QGIS 3.2 yet. Might be better if you posted a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) regarding this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a dropdown for shortest or fastest path.
[image]